Changing Taskbar Background Color to transparent via Win32 API or registry on Windows 11
I have a question, how to change background of Taskbar to fully transparent via Win32 API or registry, so Start button, pinned icons, tray and etc. will be not affected by change of transparency?
I tried to change it, using SetWindowCompositionAttribute and ACCENT_ENABLE_TRANSPARENTGRADIENT with Color Transparent but it works on Windows 10 and not 11

If you want to turn on the Transparency effects in settings, you could try to set the value of EnableTransparency to 1 in the Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize.

I want to achieve fully transparent color as background color for Taskbar, so this is solution will not suite my case

It seems that full transparent taskbar not supported in Windows 11. Refer to the thread:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-get-a-transparent-taskbar-in-windows-11/8ff079dc-33a8-494a-b2ce-7500aa353d2c

Can you convert please your comment to answer, so i will be able to check it as answer to Issue?

It seems that full transparent taskbar not supported in Windows 11. Refer to the thread: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-get-a-transparent-taskbar-in-windows-11/8ff079dc-33a8-494a-b2ce-7500aa353d2c

TranslucentTB seems to be in disagreement with this statement.
